# Serialized Header Detail into JSON Object Hierarchy

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have two DataTable, RCPT_HEADER and RCPT_DETAIL and trying to serialize into json object hierarchy using Json.NET / C#.
I've already tried code

```
static JArray DataToArray(string connString, string query)
        {
            JArray jArray = new JArray();
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            int fieldcount = reader.FieldCount;
                            object[] values = new object[fieldcount];
                            reader.GetValues(values);
                            JObject jo = new JObject();

                            for (int index = 0; index < fieldcount; index++)
                            {
                                jo.Add(reader.GetName(index).ToString(), values[index].ToString());
                            }
                            jArray.Add(jo);
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                WriteLog("[DataToArray]: " + e.Message);
            }
            return jArray;
        }
```

and

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    Hashtable config = getSettings(AppPath() + "mware.config");
                    string connString = config["cs"].ToString();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
                    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
                    jsonWriter.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
                    JObject jObject = new JObject();
                    JArray jArray = new JArray();

                    jObject.Add("RCPT_HEADER", DataToArray(connString, "SELECT * FROM RCPT_HEADER"));
                    jObject.Add("RCPT_DETAIL", DataToArray(connString, "SELECT * FROM RCPT_DETAIL"));
                    jObject.WriteTo(jsonWriter);
                    Console.WriteLine(jObject.ToString());
                    Console.ReadLine();
                } 
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    WriteLog("[postJSON]: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
```

but I'm gettin output like this:

```
 {
    "RCPT_HEADER": [
        {
            "RECORD_ID": "1",
            "ACTION_CODE": "SAVE",
            "CONDITION": "Ready",
            "DATE_TIME_STAMP": "9/11/2015 12:00:00 AM"
        }
    ],
    "RCPT_DETAIL": [
        {
            "RECORD_ID": "1",
            "ACTION_CODE": "SAVE",
            "CONDITION": "Ready",
            "LINK_ID": "1",
            "ITEM": "SKU00048700007683",
            "DATE_TIME_STAMP": "9/11/2015 12:00:00 AM"
        },
        {
            "RECORD_ID": "2",
            "ACTION_CODE": "SAVE",
            "CONDITION": "Ready",
            "LINK_ID": "1",
            "ITEM": "SKU00048700007684",
            "DATE_TIME_STAMP": "9/11/2015 12:00:00 AM"
        }
    ]
}
```

Actually, I would like it to return the output like this:

```
{
    "RCPT_HEADER": [
        {
            "RECORD_ID": "1",
            "ACTION_CODE": "SAVE",
            "CONDITION": "Ready",
            "DATE_TIME_STAMP": "9/11/2015 12:00:00 AM",
            "RCPT_DETAIL": [
                {
                    "RECORD_ID": "1",
                    "ACTION_CODE": "SAVE",
                    "CONDITION": "Ready",
                    "LINK_ID": "1",
                    "ITEM": "SKU00048700007683",
                    "DATE_TIME_STAMP": "9/11/2015 12:00:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "RECORD_ID": "2",
                    "ACTION_CODE": "SAVE",
                    "CONDITION": "Ready",
                    "LINK_ID": "1",
                    "ITEM": "SKU00048700007684",
                    "DATE_TIME_STAMP": "9/11/2015 12:00:00 AM"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the first time I have tried to use JSON.NET.

Comment: Please, show your code where you actually serialize your datatables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using data tables, it will serialize tables this way as a JSON array of tables.
You can write your own `JsonConverter` in order to serialize it your way. Here is [a good article](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/).

However, in my opinion, there is another good but hacky solution: if you always have the same structure and it is not requiring too much performance, it will be easier to deserialize it again, move this object and serialize it back.
Something like this:

```
string json = "YOUR_JSON_RESULT";

JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);

((JObject)jsonObject["RCPT_HEADER"][0])
        .Properties()
        .Last()
        .AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("RCPT_DETAIL", jsonObject["RCPT_DETAIL"]));
jsonObject.Remove("RCPT_DETAIL");

string jsonResult = jsonObject.ToString();
```

There is another one solution which is elegant and sounds proper. You use data tables but you need it to become serialized like it is not a table by implementing custom serializers or modificators. Probably, you just don't need data tables.
Do not use it if possible - use your own classes instead, so that you can describe any nesting and serialization order:

```
public class RcptDetail
{
    public string RECORD_ID { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}

public class RcptHeader
{
    public string RECORD_ID { get; set; }
    /* ... */
    public RcptDetail RCPT_DETAIL { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeldar Kurmangaliyev. It is now working perfectly. YOU ROCK...!! Thanks